# Multiple zookeeper nodes causing out of memory issue?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I am  running 3 zookeeper instances on two servers as a cluster of 6 and i am running zookeeper using zkServer.sh script without any Java parameter on 64 bit Red Hat Linux with 12G of RAM on each server.

Now as i understood that for each unspecified java process, it takes around 25% of total RAM and i have 3 zookeeper instances, i could see that after a sometime, i get connection reset errors with zookeepers and very low memory left.

Can anybody suggest how can i control zookeeper nodes limited by predefined memory specs such as -Xms & -Xmx to avoid these issues as my cluster does not work properly due to this issue?

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add JVM parameters to zookeeper, create file named java.env under conf folder in each of zookeeper with below content.

```
export JVMFLAGS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```